# If Statement not working as expected Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

I have put together the following script. What I would like to do is if the VM name is like *DC* or *SQL* then set the tag to $false or if it is anything else set the tag to $true.

If I take the If stateents out, it works fine, but it sets the DC and SQL tags to $true, I thought if I put in `If ($vm.name -like *dc*)`   I could set the tag to $false, same for SQL.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
   [string]$RG

)
$rgs = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | Where-Object {$_.ResourceGroupName -like "*$rg*"} 
foreach ($rg in $rgs) 
{
$vms = Get-AzureRmVm -ResourceGroupName $rg.ResourceGroupName
    foreach ($vm in $vms) 
    {
    if ($vm.Name -like *dc*)
        {
        $tags = $_.Tags
        $tags['ShutdownSchedule_AllowStop'] = "$False";
        Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $_.Id -Tag $tags -Force -Verbose
        }
    Elseif ($vm.Name -like *SQL*)
        {
        $tags = $_.Tags
        $tags['ShutdownSchedule_AllowStop'] = "$False";
        Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $_.Id -Tag $tags -Force -Verbose
        }
     Else 
        {
        $tags = $_.Tags
        $tags['ShutdownSchedule_AllowStop'] = "$True";
        Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $_.Id -Tag $tags -Force -Verbose
        }
    }
}
```

The script that works is below

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
   [string]$RG

)

$start = Get-Date
$rgs = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | Where-Object {$_.ResourceGroupName -like "*$rg*"} 
foreach ($rg in $rgs) 
{
$vms = Get-AzureRmVm -ResourceGroupName $rg.ResourceGroupName
    $vms.ForEach({
        $tags = $_.Tags
        $tags['ShutdownSchedule_AllowStop'] = "$True";
        Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $_.Id -Tag $tags -Force -Verbose
  })
}
```

The error I'm getting is around  `if ($vm.Name -like *dc*)` Error is "You must provide value Expression following the * Operator" Same for SQL if.

And also an error (which has completely baffled me)

```
    }
}
```

Last two lines erroring with "Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement"

Any help please before I crash google?

Thanks :)

Comment: sometimes you're using quotes in your like statement and sometimes not. Do you do this with a purpose? Try using quotes!  `if ($vm.Name -like '*dc*')`

Comment: @Olaf This is exactly it. To add to this; single quotes are fine if there are not variables. Double quotes should be used when there are variables, like in Norrin's `$_.ResourceGroupName -like "*$rg*"`

Comment: @Olaf Thanks both for your quick replies, works perfectly. Thanks for your help (can't believe I missed the quotes.. I should take sundays off) .. thanks again, appreciate it :)

Comment: I usually end up using '-match' if the context would support it. Much simpler to use than `-like'.

Comment: @RohinSidharth - You need to be careful with `-match`; it will interpret its argument as a regular expression.